Why is this Vitest test for a thunk returning incorrectly?
When a player is 1 or 2 spaces away from an npc, the npc moves away by 1 through a dispatched thunk.
This works well in my project but I'm struggling to replicate it in my tests. I'm probably missing something painfully obvious. I am using redux-toolkit and vitest.
So I currently have things set up like this:
describe('thunks', () => {
  it('should dispatch moveNpcAction and update state when handleUncaughtChickenResponse is called', async () => {
    const initialState = {
      actors: mockActors1,
      map: mockMap1
    };

    // Mock store methods
    const dispatch = vi.fn();
    const getState = vi.fn((): RootState => initialState);

    // Perform the action
    await handleUncaughtChickenResponse()(dispatch, getState, undefined);

   
    // Check that the dispatch function was called with the correct action
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(moveNpcAction({ id: 'chicken1', dx: 1, dy: 0 }));

    // Check if state updates as expected
    const updatedState = getState();
    expect(updatedState.actors.npcs[0].position).toEqual({ x: 2, y: 2 });
  });
});

Within the thunk the console.logs confirm that the right information is getting to moveNPC action:
    console.log('confirm moveNpcAction arguments', { id: npc.id, dx: moveX, dy: moveY });

And then in the slice I have:
  moveNpcAction: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ id: string; dx: number; dy: number }>) => 
{
  const npc = state.npcs.find(n => n.id === action.payload.id);
  if (npc) {
    npc.position.x += action.payload.dx;
    npc.position.y += action.payload.dy;
  }

  console.log('new npc location', state.npcs[0].position)

},
          dispatch(moveNpcAction({ id: npc.id, dx: moveX, dy: moveY }));

The npc location log is giving me nothing:
  new npc location <ref *1> {
  type_: 0,
  scope_: {
    drafts_: [ [Object], [Array], [Object], [Circular *1] ],
    parent_: undefined,
    immer_: Immer2 {
      autoFreeze_: true,
      useStrictShallowCopy_: false,
      produce: [Function (anonymous)],
      produceWithPatches: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    canAutoFreeze_: true,
    unfinalizedDrafts_: 0
  },
  modified_: false,
  finalized_: false,
  assigned_: {},
...
}

and then the following line fails:
expect(updatedState.actors.npcs[0].position).toEqual({ x: 2, y: 2 });

Any idea what I might be missing?

Simply, because as a user you'd never call a thunk like this:
handleUncaughtChickenResponse()(dispatch, getState, undefined);

Calling it like that is an implementation detail of the thunk middleware.
Instead, a thunk is called like this:
dispatch(handleUncaughtChickenResponse())

Your test is honestly too far from reality. The moment you mock dispatch, you lose all connection to how thunks and a Redux store would actually work.
Better write your tests with a real Redux store instead of trying to mock parts of it.

Interesting. I have editted the original post to show my full test. The thunk only needs to be called under set circumstances how would I set the store to reflect this without impacting the initial store outside of tests?

@JamesWard-Sinclair Create an actual Redux store with the preloaded state you want to test with for each unit test case.
